# JSon Serialize complex object with datatable inside

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization, datatable

I have this kind of object:

```
Public Class ClasseProva
Inherits RM_Base

Public Sub New()
    Me.NomeTabella = "ClasseProva"
End Sub

Private m_AZI_ID As Integer
Public Property AZI_ID() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_AZI_ID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        m_AZI_ID = value
    End Set
End Property

Private m_dtPROGETTI As DataTable

Public Function ProgettiRO() As DataTable
    Return m_dtPROGETTI
End Function

Public Sub ProgettiWO(value As DataTable)
    m_dtPROGETTI = value
End Sub

End Class
```

So if in my object there is no datatable, I know how to serialize using Json and use serialized object as cookie. So in this way I have

```
public ClasseProva CookieClasseProva
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            string myObjectJson = Request.Cookies["CookieClasseProva"].Value;
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClasseProva>(myObjectJson);
        }
        catch { return null; }
    }
    set
    {
        string myObjectJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        var cookie = new HttpCookie("CookieClasseProva", myObjectJson)
        {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)
        };
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
}
```

But after I added datatable, serialization function doesn't serialize datatable.

EDIT:

I don't know how attach a project. But now I'm copying Class of my BL project

```
    Public Class Class1
        Private m_intValue As Integer
        Public Property MyIntValue() As Integer
            Get
                Return m_intValue
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                m_intValue = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private m_dtValue As DataTable
        Public Property MyDatatable() As DataTable
            Get
                Return m_dtValue
            End Get

            Set(value As DataTable)
                m_dtValue = value
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class
```

and code section of a simple page

```
    Imports Newtonsoft.Json
    Imports DatatableSerializationBL

    Public Class _Default
        Inherits Page

        Public Property CookieUtente() As Class1
            Get
                Try
                    Dim myObjectJson As String = Request.Cookies("CookieUtente").Value
                    Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Class1)(myObjectJson)
                Catch
                    Return Nothing
                End Try
            End Get
            Set(value As Class1)
                Dim myObjectJson As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value)
                Dim cookie = New HttpCookie("CookieUtente", myObjectJson)
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
            End Set
        End Property

        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            Dim c As New Class1
            c.MyIntValue = 1
            c.MyDatatable = New DataTable
            c.MyDatatable.NewRow()
            CookieUtente = c
            Console.WriteLine(CookieUtente.MyDatatable.Rows.Count)
        End Sub

    End Class
```

So in the design page , I print rows.count value and  it prints 0

```
ROWS : <%= CookieUtente.MyDatatable.Rows.Count%>
```

Comment: Well... first) Your first code block is visual basic and not c# second) you surely got some error message - tell us :) third) after a short test i can say that `DataTable`'s could be (de)serialzied - so there must be another problem, f.e: the data table contains data types or values that could not be serialized by default serialization. If thats the case, have a look at the custom-converters you can write - that way you will have full control over your serialized data!

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with JSON and c# or vb.net code (one or the other please) that fully demonstrates the problem, ideally as a console app?  You might want to read [ask] and take the [tour]; both have suggestions for how to write questions that are more likely to get answered.